# Image from gallery not displaying on img tag in ionic 2

Tags: android, angular, image, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to display image from gallery to `img` tag. But image not showing on `img` tag. But it is working with `PhotoViewer` . below is my code.

```
 options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
   //mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
  }
```

Image captured with

```
this.camera.getPicture(this.options).then((imageData) => {

  alert(imageData)
  this.photoViewer.show(imageData);
  this.captureDataUrl=imageData;

 }, (err) => {
  // Handle error
 });
```

in HTML

```
<img [src]="captureDataUrl" *ngIf="captureDataUrl"/>
```

If I am using sourceType as camera (`sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA`),it also working,it displays image on img tag, But  not working on if i use sourceType as `sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY`  . Please help

Comment: Did you get any error in console like `SecurityTrustUrl`?

Comment: yeah. this is the error .unsafe:content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A81 .  but its working on PhotoViewer

Comment: For `.unsafe:content` error we have to bypass SecurityTrustUrl using `DomSanitizationService` for more information refer this link https://devfanaticblog.com/working-with-camera-in-ionic-2-and-ionic-native/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi have the same problem in ios,
I resolve this problem by doing the following step

```
            var options = {
                  quality: 80,
                  allowEdit: true,
                  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                  saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
                  correctOrientation: true,
                  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
                  //encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
                };


                this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
                      // Special handling for Android library  // 
                      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
                        this.ImageData = imagePath.replace(/^file:\/\//, '');
                      }
                      else {
                        this.ImageData = imagePath;
                      }
                      this.photos.push(this.ImageData); //if you have to show multiple image
                      this.photos.reverse();
            }
```

Html section

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col col-3 *ngFor="let photo of photos; let id = index">
                    <ion-card class="block">
                      <ion-icon name="ios-close-circle-outline" class="deleteIcon" (click)="deletePhoto(id)"></ion-icon>
                      <img [src]="photo" *ngIf="photo" />
                    </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.Its working fine. Could you please tell me whats wrong with my code.