# BASE64 plugin not working in ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, base64, ionic3

I need to convert image to base 64 format which I capture either from camera or from gallery and then send that string to my REST Api.I have tried many things but the most stable solution I came across was using `Base 64 package`-https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/
But neither it giving me any error nor it is generating the string.
Below is my code:

```
  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
      this.base64.encodeFile(imagePath).then((base64Image: string) => {
        console.log(base64Image);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.base64Image=err;
      });
      if (this.platform.is('android') && sourceType === this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
        this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath)
          .then(filePath => {
            let correctPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imagePath.lastIndexOf('?'));
            this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
          });
      }
      else {
        var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        var correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
      }
    }, (err) => {
      this.presentToast('Error while selecting image.');
    });
```

Comment: In CameraOptions,
    
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    
    return Return image as base64-encoded string

Comment: I need to show that image as well on the view so I cant make it base64 at the time of getting it.

Comment: You can also show your selected image on view with destination type  `this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` by passing `<img src="dataURLImage"`

Comment: please show me by code snippet.I am new to ionic so i ain't getting you.

Comment: Check this, I already have given answer to this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920164/image-from-gallery-not-displaying-on-img-tag-in-ionic-2/47922259#47922259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for encoding, the camera plugin returns a BASE64 string with the correct options, this is a piece of my working code.

```
let opcoes = {
  maximumImagesCount: 1,
  sourceType: 1,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  destinationType: 0, // USE THIS TO RETURN BASE64 STRING
  correctOrientation: true
};

this.camera.getPicture(opcoes).then(res => {
  this.picture= res;
  console.log('check the string', res);
  // IT RETURNS ONLY THE IMAGE STRING WITHOUT THE data:image, IF YOU WANT TO
  // SHOW YOUR PICTURE JUST APPEND THE STRING BELLOW TO YOUR RETURNED STRING AND USE IT TO DISPLAY
  this.pictureForExibition = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + res;
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

In your HTML

```
<!-- JUST USE AN *ngIf TO CHECK IF THE PROPERTY ISN'T NULL OR IT'LL THROW ERROR FOR THE INVALID SRC -->
<img [src]="pictureForExibition" *ngIf="pictureForExibition" alt="base64 image" />
```

Hope this helps