# Ionic 3 Text file is uploaded into android but not in Ios?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

First i create Text file and download into mobile and file successfully saved for both ios and android

file:///Users/MacBookPro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4A91E6EF-A1C1-4ACD-B986-DC4DF3B7612F/data/Containers/Data/Application/B2332191-8726-4881-B393-40C6FDDA0F5C/Documents/result.txt

that is native path and no error and byte also sent but file is not uploaded for ios

```
   var res = 'data:text/plain,' + 
      encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.mydataishere));
      const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
      fileTransfer.download(res, 
      this.file.dataDirectory+'result.txt').then((entry) => {
      console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
     this.performancerecord(entry.toURL());
   })
```

Then try to upload file

```
performancerecord(file){
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'performance',
      fileName: 'Result'+this.id+'.txt',
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: "text/plain",
      }
      console.info(options.fileName)
       const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
       fileTransfer.upload(file, 'url', options)
       .then((data) => {
        console.info(data);
        }, (err) => {
       console.info(err);
       });
    }
```

For android no problem but in ios text file not uploading to server..................

Comment: what does `entry.toURL()` print in console ?

Comment: native path where my file is downloaded

Comment: is it ios 11? in which case you may need to normalize url

Comment: no sir i phone 6 plus/Ios 9.3

Comment: weird..any console logs or error log?

Comment: Please add the details to the question and not in comments

Comment: sir can you explain what can normalize url do

Comment: thats because of change in IOS 11.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708792/4826457

Comment: can i Convert navtive file path to file url[NSUrl] with ionic 2

Comment: not sure I understand that.. isnt `file:///Users/MacBookPro/Library/Developer/` the NSURL? never had to use NSURL directly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164139/discussion-between-manoj-bhardwaj-and-suraj-rao).

Comment: i am trying with simulator so this is native path for my case

Comment: can i use resolvefilesystem url and then upload the file

Comment: you could try.. but its really same as using https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/

Comment: hi i have same problem with ios, I resolved like 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920164/image-from-gallery-not-displaying-on-img-tag-in-ionic-2/47922259#47922259

Comment: Thank you sir but i have No problem with image uploading